# SharePoint-hosted app - server side code?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-apps

I'm doing a SharePoint-hosted app. Can you use any server side code? Or is it just HTML, CSS, REST API:s and JavaScript?
Just only can use server side code to develop Provider-hosted apps and Auto-hosted apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use server side code in Sharepoint hosted app.

Please check:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f411770-b397-4980-940d-53a20ee63a19/server-side-code-in-sharepoint-hosted-app

Answer (score 0):

There are no server side code can use within your SharePoint Hosted App.

**SharePoint Hosted App:** HTML,CSS, JavaScript (with the SharePoint 2013 JSOM library).

**Provider/Auto-App:** Any language supported by your web server or hosting service.

Also noted that in SharePoint Hosted App there are **no elevation of privilege capabilities**, because this app can only run in signed-in user context and have privileges of the signed-in user in Host Web (by default)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Hosted Apps (now known as Add-Ins) cannot use any type of server side code. This is because SharePoint Hosted Add Ins reside in their own app domain; isolated from the site / site collection they are deployed on. They are not deployed to the farm through as .WSP like previous versions of SharePoint applications (before SharePoint 2013)

Auto-Hosted apps are supported
https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2014/05/16/update-on-autohosted-apps-preview-program/

Provider Hosted Add Ins can use any language or technology available to include the client side technologies you listed (js/css/html), but you must configure and maintain the applicable hardware or server(s). Provider Hosted Add Ins, like SharePoint Hosted Add Ins are not deployed to SharePoint and must run on their own servers.